java - soap xml document character Invocation arguments were modified at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
I have a java class XMLHelper.java that has a method called parseFromString. This method receives a string xml soap request, parses it and converts it into a Document. This method convert the hex characters into UTF-8. I dont know if this is correct...
In the photo example, after dBuilder.parse(is), the character & #xED; transform to "í".
public class XMLHelper {

    public static DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = null;
    
    static {
        dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        dbFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
    }
    
    public static SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    
        
    public static Document parseFromString (String xmlInString) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = XMLHelper.dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        
        InputSource is = new InputSource (new StringReader(xmlInString));
        

        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
        
        return doc;
    }
....
}

I need the parse keep the character "& #xED;".
Then, the code continues with this:
    soapEnvelopeRequest = XMLHelper.parseFromString(toString(soapEnvelopeRequest));
    
    wsSecHeader.insertSecurityHeader(soapEnvelopeRequest);
    wsSecSignature.prepare(soapEnvelopeRequest, crypto, wsSecHeader);
    
    // Modificacion y firma de la peticion
    secSOAPReqDoc = wsSecSignature.build(soapEnvelopeRequest, crypto,
            wsSecHeader);
    
    element = secSOAPReqDoc.getDocumentElement();
    // Transformacion del elemento DOM a String
    source = new DOMSource(element);
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    streamResult = new StreamResult(baos);
    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer()
            .transform(source, streamResult);
    secSOAPReq = new String(baos.toByteArray());
    // Creacion de un nuevo mensaje SOAP a partir del mensaje SOAP
    // securizado formado
    MessageFactory mf = new org.apache.axis.soap.MessageFactoryImpl();
    res = mf.createMessage(null,
            new ByteArrayInputStream(secSOAPReq.getBytes()));
    
    return res;

The variable baos transform the character into this: "Ã­" (UTF-8 bytes as Latin-1 characters bytes  Ã) and i got this error:
org.apache.axis.AxisFault: ; nested exception is: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation arguments were modified at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)

Thanks.

The string &#xED is a Character Reference as defined in the XML specification, and refers to the unicode code point U+00ED, í. The XML parser has no choice other than converting that string into the Java (UTF-16) character 0x00ED. Why do you think it's wrong to decode a character reference?

i got it... maybe the error is not in the DocumentBuilderFactory parse... i edited the question with all the information and the error

Well, ok, this is a classical UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 encoding error/problem. The Unicode character "LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE", U+00ED, or í, is encoded in UTF-8 as 0xC3AD. If you would interpret that byte sequence in ISO-8859-1 you would see 0xC3, or U+003C, "Latin capital letter A with tilde", and 0xAD which is a "soft hyphen", i.e. a symbol that will only be visible if it is involved n a line break.
So, you need to better control the chain of deserialization and serialization of your XML data and make sure that all stages produces and interprets the byte sequence correctly.
You should start with specifying the encodings used when converting between byte sequences and strings and vice versa, otherwise you depend on platform defaults, which might surprise you.
Hope this helps

ok, the exact moment that the "ì" transform to "Ã" is here:
// Transformacion del elemento DOM a String   .......   TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer()     .transform(source, streamResult);
Do you mean that I have to tell the transform that the encoding is UTF-8? How i do that? Thanks again.

ok, i edit my post to say that there are no fault in the DocumentBuilder parse. it do correct to transform into "í". the character Ã only appear in my console when i do println, but in the soap request it send "í"... my error was in another method that has nothing to do with this.
